# Is it possible to print only if true using ternary in C#?

Tags: c#

Normally if I wanted to print given a boolean I would do something like:

```
if (myBool){
   //log here
}
```

But is it possible to shorten it to something simpler with ternaries?

Comment: The answer is no, well apart from `if (myBool) //log here`. or passing in the condition to your log method, or some sort of action which will likely be longer anyway. For what its worth don't be afraid of verbose and explicit code.

Comment: This question has a bit of a A/B problem smell. What is the actual goal here?

Comment: Really just trying to see if there are less verbose ways to type out these kinds of snippets. But for now seems like this might be the cleanest and most legible.

Comment: Could you elaborate the `shorten it to something simpler with ternaries` part a bit?

Comment: It sounds like you have a home-rolled logging framework. I'd really suggest switching to one of the many common open source frameworks that support things like log levels. https://nlog-project.org/ or https://serilog.net/ for example.

Comment: Note that making it a habit to _always_ try to shorten your code is a really bad practice. Shortened code is often harder to read and _will_ come to bite you when someone makes a small change that causes a bug that is difficult to spot. Don't get me wrong though; do shorten your code but only when it doesn't come at the price of readability. And remember that [_"Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand."_](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler)

Comment: Also, if your end goal is really to write the fewest number of characters, `if (myBool) Log();` (as suggested by MichaelRandall) is going to be shorter than any "hacky" form of ternary expression you can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Well there's this, but it's ugly:

```
Console.Write( mybool? /* Log here */ + "\n" : "");
```

You can also make a method with the bool as an argument:

```
public void Log(string Message, bool reallyLog = true)
{
    if (reallyLog) //...
}
```

Comment: The first would still result in a print. A newline yes but still a print. I'm trying to get 0 prints if the boolean is false.

Comment: @PhantomQuest No, it wouldn't. `Console.WriteLine("");` would but not `Console.Write("");`.

Comment: Also consider making the message be a `Func<string>` (to be closer to the original code). In the off chance that generating the message throws an exception in the "don't log" case. ;)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

The ternary operator is to shorter `IF ... THEN ... ELSE ...`.

But here you only do a `IF ... THEN ...` and have no `ELSE` clause.

So the ternary operator is irrelevant and inapplicable.

But you can use a state variable and a method to encapsulate the behavior and avoid to test each time you want to log if enabled:

```
public class Logger
{
  public bool Enabled { get; set; }
  
  public void Write(string message)
  {
    if (Enabled)
      DoWrite(message);
  }

  public void WriteLine(string message)
  {
    if (Enabled)
      DoWriteLine(message);
  }
}
```